# Converting from Overleaf to TexMaker and having bibliography problems

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

I need to now use a local Latex compiler and have started using Texmaker.  I have two files, my main file and a .bib file but keep getting errors that the bibliography is empty.  I have a feeling some of the commands I used in overleaf just aren't compatible with Texmaker. I have looked through the many other questions related to this but can't find the answer.  My basic code is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
My text \cite{ref1}

\printbibliography[title = mybib.bib]

\end{document}
```

then my bibliography file is:
@techreport{ref1,
title = {Title},
author = {author},
year = {2012},
url = {https://url.com}
}

When I compile, I go to mybib.bib and run BibTex.  Then I go to the main file and run PDFLatex twice.  And I still get warnings that 'Citation 'ref1' is undefined'.

I have a feeling that I'm missing a basic command that Texmaker needs that overleaf didn't.

Comment: You need to run biber, not bibtex. Also you first need to run `pdflatex filename`, then `biber filename_without_ending` and then pdflatex again.

Comment: To make this more comfortable you could use `latexmk -pdf filename`, that's what overleaf uses behind the scenes.

Comment: (if you are just starting with a local editor, I would suggest texstudio instead of texmaker. It used to be a clone of texmaker, but evolved into a very powerful editor)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, pefect, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!